# How unboxing works in C++? Why is it not recursive?

Tags: c++

```
class C {
    int x;
public:
    C(int x) : x{x} {}
    operator int () { return x; }
};

class CR {
    C& cr;
public:
    CR(C& cr) : cr{cr} {}
    operator C& () { return cr; }
};

class CRR {
    CR& crr;
public:
    CRR(CR& crr) : crr{crr} {}
    operator CR& () { return crr; }
};

int main () {
    C c(5);
    CR cr(c);
    CRR crr(cr);
    std::cout << crr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the std:cout throws an error. Explicit casting -- ((int)(C&)(CR&)crr) works. Why is this not done automatically by the compiler? Is there a better way to do it? Or is this not supposed to be done?

Comment: There is no unboxing in C++, there are cases where compiler allows implicit constructor calls and type conversions, no more than that.

Comment: There's no such thing as "unboxing" in C++. C++ does not work this way. The equivalent approach to this, in C++, is called "operator overloading". You must have Java, or C#, background. You will do yourself a favor if you completely forget about Java/C#, when trying to learn C++. Despite the similar syntax, C++ is a completely different language, has completely different fundamental concepts, and works in a fundamentally different way. The longer you keep thinking about Java/C#, the longer you will simply confuse yourself, and waste time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Except of the word "unboxing", this does not really look very Java-influenced to me. The very fact that the OP uses operator overloading in the first place shows that he or she is actively trying to use C++ idioms, doesn't it?

Comment: No. The operator overloading the OP uses are the ones that were copied from the C++ textbook. I'm sure that introductory textbooks show you a `std::cout << "hello world"` before fully explaining how operator overloading works.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this not done automatically by the compiler?

Because the C++ language says so. It would make the code harder to read and reason about, and it would make it easier to create bugs. In short, it's not worth the trouble.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion:

> When considering the argument to a constructor or to a user-defined
>   conversion function, only one standard conversion sequence is allowed
>   (otherwise user-defined conversions could be effectively chained)

It's for the same reason that `std::string` does not have a `char const*` conversion operator, and `std::vector` does not a have a `T*` conversion operator. They instead have member functions like `c_str()` or `data()` which make it obvious what's going on.

> Is there a better way to do it?

Turn your operators into explicitly named member functions like `ToCr()` or `Cr()`.